# Pandas extract substring

Tags: pandas, regex, string, dataframe, extract

I have a large text file with strings contained in a single column (["string"])like in the example below:

```
    string
0   7 ABC MAGAZINE                                          51               09/14/2000 09/14/2000                .00
1   ABC Magazine                      970-663-4007                               0    00/00/0000                .00
```

My goal is to extract those line items which contain one sequence that resembles the format of a date "mm/dd/yyyy" into a separate dataframe.

```
    result
0   ABC Magazine                      970-663-4007                               0    00/00/0000                .00
```

I tried using regex, but both lines got selected instead of just one. How can I avoid this?

What I tried:

```
df_['result']=df['string'].str.extract('(.*\d\d/\\d\d/\\d\d\d\d.*)')
```

Comment: doesn't the `09/14/2000` in the first line match a date? Should the date be valid (in which case `00/00/000` shouldn't match)

Comment: As long as it's in the format of dd/dd/dddd, it should match.   The first one with the 9/14/2000 shouldn't match because it repeats more than once.  There are two sequences, and I want only lines extracted that contain only one occurrence, like in the second one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex with [`str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) to ensure having a single match:

```
regex = '\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}'

out = df[df['string'].str.count(regex).eq(1)]
```

output:

```
                                              string
1  ABC Magazine                      970-663-4007...
```